# Data encryption on PhoneGap applications?

Tags: encryption, cordova

My company develops mobile apps that require encryption in their functionality for multiple platforms - iPhone, BlackBerry, J2ME, WinMobile, and probably Android in the near future. I've been trying to find ways to develop our apps such that all the app logic can be developed in a single code-base with a different UI wrapper for each platform, and PhoneGap seems like a promising solution.

What I want to ask is, would it be possible for an app developed in PhoneGap to use encryption like 3DES, AES, MD5, SHA256 etc? Since as far as I understand a PhoneGap app would be written with web dev technologies like Javascript/CSS, and I'm not too sure about the encryption functionalities they provide. (I'm more of an app developer than a web developer)

I thought of making my own helper classes to do this, but am not sure if those classes will be portable across all platforms. For example, if I make those classes using Java, will they be usable on an iPhone? And how?

Or if anybody knows of an even better way to do this, please share it. Thanks!

-Quinn

Comment: MD5 isn't encryption. It's hashing.

Answer (score 2):

The major smartphone APIs are all very different from each other (iPhone:  objC, Android:  modern Java, Blackberry:  old J2ME Java).

When you drop out of Phonegap to go native you'll almost certainly need code specific to each platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in JavaScript - because the JS is compiled into phonegap you don't need to worry about its integrity, plus you can code in your public key allowing your private key to be picked up later.

see http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/ which looks like an RSA implementation (which is asymetric if thats what your after). For symettric, try implementing AES - its only a dozen lines or so of C so shouldn't be too hard to port?.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should be looking for entirely-javascript implementations of the various relevant protocols.

Generally, I only look for the industry standard encryption and hashing plus very open licensing (sometimes the GPL does not work for clients)

Currently I will be trying [SlowAES](http://code.google.com/p/slowaes/) for AES and [jsSHA2](http://anmar.eu.org/projects/jssha2/) for SHA-512

I will report back on my results with these.